# iText7 Change Size of PDF

Tags: pdf, resize, itext7

We would like to standardize the size of documents that come into our system.  Sometimes, the PDFs are way too small, or way too large for what we prefer.

I am looking for a method to manipulate one of the PDFs and change them into either PageSize.LETTER or PageSize.LEGAL.

This is something we could easily do with iTextSharp, but I am struggling to get the same to work with iText7.

Any examples of taking an existing PDF and resizing them would be helpful.

Thanks!

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("outputpath");
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourcePath);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

// Use first page of document
PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(1);
Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

Rectangle newPageSize;
bool isLandscape = false;
float ratio;
float LetterAspectRatio = 1.2941f;
float LegalAspectRatio = 1.6471f;
float AspectRatioDifference = LegalAspectRatio - LetterAspectRatio;
float HalfAspectRatioDifference = AspectRatioDifference / 2;

//If the width is greater than the height, it is landscape. We will need to know this later when we 
//transform the page
if (pageSize.GetWidth() > pageSize.GetHeight())
{
    ratio = pageSize.GetWidth() / pageSize.GetHeight();
    isLandscape = true;
}
else
{
    ratio = pageSize.GetHeight() / pageSize.GetWidth();
}

//If the size ratio is greater than Letter, move on to Legal
if (ratio > LetterAspectRatio)
{
    //If the ratio is less than Legal, but greater than Letter, we have a decision to make
    if (ratio < LegalAspectRatio)
    {
        //If the ratio is closer to Legal than it is to Letter, go with Legal
        if (ratio - LetterAspectRatio > HalfAspectRatioDifference)
        {
            newPageSize = PageSize.LEGAL;
        }
        else //If the ratio is closer to Letter than it is to Legal, go with Letter
        {
            newPageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
        }
    }
    else //If the ratio is greater than Legal, shrink it to Legal
    {
        newPageSize = PageSize.LEGAL;
    }
}
else //If the ratio is smaller than Letter, stretch it to letter
{
    newPageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
}

pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(newPageSize));
Document newDocument = new Document(pdfDocument, new PageSize(newPageSize));
newDocument.Close();
```